# Can I see who I'm sitting next to while selecting my seat online?

Tags: air-travel, klm, privacy

I have in the past had a not-so-pleasant experience of sitting near some passengers with bad odour or who were too talkative. I was wondering if I could see who I'm sitting near when selecting my seats online before the flight?

I heard that KLM offered this.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that KLM violates the GDPR by giving you information about another passenger.

Comment: And if they did tell you it was FirstName LastName -- how would you then be able to evaluate how talkative or smelly they are? This is not a feasible plan.

Comment: How do you describe yourself when making an online reservation, so that others can deside if they want to sit next to you?

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Talkative and smelly, so nobody wants to sit next to me.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I see who I'm sitting next to while selecting my seat online?

No, unless if

- the airline gives some option for passengers to share their details, e.g. for some [seat and meet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/klm-meet-seat-use-facebook-linkedin-to-pick-seat-mates/) social service.
- cheating the system, e.g. bribing airline employees or bypassing some security

---

More details about the [Meet & Seat at KLM](https://www.zdnet.com/article/klm-meet-seat-use-facebook-linkedin-to-pick-seat-mates/):

> KLM Royal Dutch Airlines has launched Meet & Seat, a new service "for meeting interesting passengers on your flight." If you have a reservation, you can link your Facebook or LinkedIn profile to the flight you'll be on, in order to see who else is on board, and decide who you want to sit with – long before the flight leaves the ground.

Comment: @Willeke ok added, good?

Comment: I am happy, changed from -1 to +1, as it now explains how it works.